# Add Markers to Google Maps based upon type of business

Tags: google-maps

Using the Google Maps Api v3 I am wandering what the simplest method is to add Markers to my map based upon a certain type of business.

E.g. Display markers of coffee shops, or dentists etc etc...

I understand this will probably be achieved by manipulating the MapOptions I am just yet to figure it out.

Thanks in advance,

- Dan

Comment: The [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) (interface to the Places API for the Google Maps API v3) returns suggested icons for different types of businesses [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?q=restaurant&address=Flushing,Queens,NY)

Answer (score 0):

I answer quickly but I guess that because you posted your question here you are building a web application and you have a MAP and you want to retrieve particular type of business and display the result on your map.

You can get the result based on certain types of business.

[This](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) is the official guide to get places:

To see which are the type of "places" the API support click [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).